# Central heating [uk] thermostatic valves

Tags: central-heating

I'm the UK in case that matters.
I have a traditional gas central heating with radiators.

As is common, the radiators have thermostatically controlled values, except for one of the radiators which does not. I believe this is necessary to have one that is not controlled?

The problem is that the one that is not controlled is the one in the main living room which is also where the main thermostat is. This room is also the one which heats up most quickly in the house. So what happens is that this room reaches its temperature before any of the others and the whole heating turns off before any of the other rooms are warm enough.

I have two options :-
1) Be cold in the rest of my house
2) Be far too hot in the living room but comfortable elsewhere.

If the livingroom had a thermostatic value, I'd at least be able to turn that one off when if got warm enough giving the rest of the house chance to heat up.

My question is, can I move the valve from a different radiator and have(say) the one in the hall be the one without a valve? Or is there a better solution?

I'd get a plumber in most likely to do this unless it's really simple to do, but just wanted to know what was possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the system is out of balance.

Every radiator usually has two valves, one at each end. One valve (the lockshield valve) is used to balance the system at installation time and is not adjustable without tools, the other is used to vary the output and can be turned by hand.

See [radiator valves explained](http://www.directheatingsupplies.co.uk/radiator-valves-explained)

[image: diagram of radiator valves]

You should be able to reduce the rate at which the room warms up by adjusting the lockshield valve slightly.

I'd try a quarter turn clockwise each morning until the system seems to be behaving as you want.

Comment: Is this a steam system or a hot water system? If it is steam, is it a 1 or 2 pipe system? How many pipes go into each radiator? It makes a difference on my answer and to solve your problem.

Comment: @d.george: In typical UK family homes, *"traditional gas central heating"* is two-pipe hot-water to radiators, not steam. Exceptions are rare.

Comment: It's hot water.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this problem would be to move the thermostat to the coldest room, remove the thermostatic valve in that  room and install a thermostatic valve in the room that originally had the thermostat This way the coldest room would get warm since the boiler would fire until the thermostat would shut it down and the other rooms would not overheat since they all would have thermostatic valves.